# Api For Scheduling Twitter Statuses As we have Schedule Posts in Facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, twitter

I am working on Twitter API's in a C# Application. Basically I am Posting Statuses on behalf of user. I know we have a 'Schedule Post' feature in Facebook API's to schedule a POST. Do we have any feature in twitter like this.

I just added 'scheduled_publish_time' parameter in Facebook Api to schedule it. Do we have anything like this in twitter ? I searched alot but i am unable to find it.

Please help if anyone do know anything about it OR let me know if i have to handle it in my application only .

Thanks

I appreciate your help.

Edits:

I am not looking for a scheduler in C#. I have used schedulers previously. I am looking for the same functionailty in API of twitter as we have in facebook. In which they provide us the functionality to schedule it later.

Comment: Take a look at hootsuite


  : https://hootsuite.com/developers/app-directory/docs/api

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Create a Scheduler (e.g. to schedule tweets, or an api request)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136983/how-create-a-scheduler-e-g-to-schedule-tweets-or-an-api-request)

Comment: @StephanWeinhold So , This functionality is not provided by twitter , we have to accomplish it on our own like using schedulers. am i right ?

Comment: @rohit-arora That's how I am interpreting the documentation, yes.

Comment: @StephanWeinhold Ok thanks.  I will use schedulers in this case then.